# SIGABRT in the Chromium WebView when calling isAppUsingDarkTheme

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

We receive interesting native crash reports from our users. According to the log, the exception happens in the `com.google.android.webview` library when requesting theme attributes, specifically `isAppUsingDarkTheme`. The final method which fails is `android::NativeApplyStyle(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, long, int, int, long, _jintArray*, long, long)`.

According to user activity logs, there is a web content shown in the WebView before the crash. Here is the full stack of the issue.

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000004e40c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #00  pc 000000000055d72c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2308)
  #00  pc 0000000000013be4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 0000000000012fb4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+320)
  #00  pc 0000000000120660  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeApplyStyle(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, long, int, int, long, _jintArray*, long, long)+348)
  #00  pc 0000000000201e20  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+240)
  #00  pc 0000000000385368  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.AssetManager.applyStyle+216)
  #00  pc 000000000038f414  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl.obtainStyledAttributes+244)
  #00  pc 00000000003896f4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes+84)
  #00  pc 00000000002b6224  /data/app/~~p8SKPpSzs5AfQaojVfFlHw==/com.google.android.webview-1wbeQSnfamx66qteIYrtdw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (kp.a+116)
  #00  pc 00000000002de064  /data/app/~~p8SKPpSzs5AfQaojVfFlHw==/com.google.android.webview-1wbeQSnfamx66qteIYrtdw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (org.chromium.android_webview.AwDarkMode.isAppUsingDarkTheme+52)
  #00  pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #00  pc 00000000005556d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+468)
  #00  pc 0000000000555870  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92)
  #00  pc 00000000003a0d58  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallBooleanMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+660)
  #00  pc 00000000044b14ec  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000)
  #00  pc 0000000001bce710  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000)
  #00  pc 0000000001bce66c  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000)
  #00  pc 0000000001bd9470  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000) (Java_J_N_MrAp8rc4+5068)
  #00  pc 000000000016f13c  /data/app/~~p8SKPpSzs5AfQaojVfFlHw==/com.google.android.webview-1wbeQSnfamx66qteIYrtdw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+188)
  #00  pc 00000000002e23a0  /data/app/~~p8SKPpSzs5AfQaojVfFlHw==/com.google.android.webview-1wbeQSnfamx66qteIYrtdw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (org.chromium.android_webview.AwSettings.populateWebPreferences+96)
  #00  pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #00  pc 00000000005556d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+468)
  #00  pc 0000000000555870  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92)
  #00  pc 00000000003abbbc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+660)
  #00  pc 0000000003b92d18  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000)
  #00  pc 0000000001bda1d4  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000)
  #00  pc 00000000043d54f4  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000)
  #00  pc 00000000023d0504  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000)
  #00  pc 0000000004b62074  /data/app/~~q2NFNMmXLCDOwTWYx91GOQ==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408834-D4_y5yNsScUQXhSZirfHYg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x6f8000) (Java_J_N_MGCvz8lp+64)
  #00  pc 000000000016932c  /data/app/~~p8SKPpSzs5AfQaojVfFlHw==/com.google.android.webview-1wbeQSnfamx66qteIYrtdw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+172)
  #00  pc 000000000035fdf8  /data/app/~~p8SKPpSzs5AfQaojVfFlHw==/com.google.android.webview-1wbeQSnfamx66qteIYrtdw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (org.chromium.ui.events.devices.InputDeviceObserver.onInputDeviceAdded [DEDUPED]+40)
  #00  pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #00  pc 00000000003185c8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
  #00  pc 000000000030e8f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996)
  #00  pc 000000000067e650  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1032)
  #00  pc 000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #00  pc 00000000004d0bf8  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.hardware.input.InputManager$InputDeviceListenerDelegate.handleMessage+32)
  #00  pc 0000000000305ef0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.7972480776628613073)+268)
  #00  pc 000000000066b988  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780)
  #00  pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #00  pc 000000000064fd64  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+180)
  #00  pc 00000000006532c4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1668)
  #00  pc 000000000040de40  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+752)
  #00  pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568)
  #00  pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228)
  #00  pc 0000000000555df0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1364)
  #00  pc 00000000004d5538  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52)
  #00  pc 000000000008a6f4  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180)
  #00  pc 00000000008d0968  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136)
  #00  pc 00000000008d912c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2444)
  #00  pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568)
  #00  pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228)
  #00  pc 000000000055482c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+448)
  #00  pc 0000000000554ce0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92)
  #00  pc 0000000000438e64  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656)
  #00  pc 000000000009b424  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124)
  #00  pc 00000000000a34e8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+836)
  #00  pc 0000000000003674  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1580)
  #00  pc 00000000000499e4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108)
```

And here is the code of the `NativeApplyStyle`, where the crash happens.

```
static void NativeApplyStyle(JNIEnv* env, jclass /*clazz*/, jlong ptr, jlong theme_ptr,
                             jint def_style_attr, jint def_style_resid, jlong xml_parser_ptr,
                             jintArray java_attrs, jlong out_values_ptr, jlong out_indices_ptr) {
  ScopedLock<AssetManager2> assetmanager(AssetManagerFromLong(ptr));
  Theme* theme = reinterpret_cast<Theme*>(theme_ptr);
  CHECK(theme->GetAssetManager() == &(*assetmanager));
  (void) assetmanager;
  ResXMLParser* xml_parser = reinterpret_cast<ResXMLParser*>(xml_parser_ptr);
  uint32_t* out_values = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(out_values_ptr);
  uint32_t* out_indices = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(out_indices_ptr);
  jsize attrs_len = env->GetArrayLength(java_attrs);
  jint* attrs = reinterpret_cast<jint*>(env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(java_attrs, nullptr));
  if (attrs == nullptr) {
    return;
  }
  ApplyStyle(theme, xml_parser, static_cast<uint32_t>(def_style_attr),
             static_cast<uint32_t>(def_style_resid), reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(attrs), attrs_len,
             out_values, out_indices);
  env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(java_attrs, attrs, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

Any thoughts?